# How to put text in the top right corner of networkx drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib, networking

I am drawing a graph and would like to add some text in the top right corner. However I am not sure how to do this. I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)


pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")
nx.draw(T, pos, node_color="y", edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)

plt.text(0,0,"******************")
plt.show()
```

to see if I could show any text at all.   It does show the asterisks in the bottom left. How do I know the resolution of the diagram so I can work out where the top right is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in [`networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html):

> draw_networkx(G, pos=None, arrows=None, with_labels=True, **kwds)
>
> > Parameters:
> >
> > > ax : Matplotlib Axes object, optional
> > > Draw the graph in the specified Matplotlib axes.

Then you can create `fig, axe = plt.subplots()` and pass `axe` to `nx.draw` and add title for `axe` then you can show title for drawing like below:

Set the title with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html), which has parameters to set the location of the title, including the use of [`matplotlib.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) arguments. (e.g. `x=1` or `loc='right'`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)

fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,7))
axe.set_title('Title for NetworkX', loc='right')

pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="dot")
nx.draw(T, pos, ax = axe, node_color="y", edge_color='#909090', node_size=200, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

- When using `x=`, the title is centered over `x` on the x-axis; adjust the value for precise positioning.

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 4))
ax1.set_title('Title for NetworkX', loc='right')

ax2.set_title('Title for NetworkX', x=.68)

ax3.set_title('Title for NetworkX', x=1)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I see "loc{'center', 'left', 'right'}, default: rcParams["axes.titlelocation"] (default: 'center')" at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html but nothing for x =1 . Is it the same as loc?